# Can't set filename of Blob

Tags: javascript, blob

I'm trying to automatically download a blob like this:

```
blobGeneratingFunction.then(blob => {
  // blob => Blob(3797539) {size: 3797539, type: "image/png"}
  let file = new Blob([blob], { type: 'application/octet-stream' })
  file.name = 'test.png'
  file.download = 'test.png'
  let blobURL = URL.createObjectURL(file)
  window.location.href = blobURL
})
```

Neither the `name` or `download` attribute managed to set the filename, which right now is:

`f486177d-6f5e-4f96-91a9-8df08e7d9da0`

How to set the filename propertly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Blob` does not have a `name` attribute.

Preserve the original `type`, and use `<a>` element with `download` attribute with `href` set to to the `Blob URL`, call `.click()` on `<a>` element after appending the element to `document.body`.

```
blobGeneratingFunction.then(blob => {
  let a = document.createElement("a") 
  let blobURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob)
  a.download = 'test.png'
  a.href = blobURL
  document.body.appendChild(a)
  a.click()
  document.body.removeChild(a)
})
```

Comment: No need to  document.body.appendChild(a); and document.body.removeChild(a);

Comment: A blob does have a name attribute - it is just read-only:
`Cannot assign to 'name' because it is a read-only property. ts(2540)`

Comment: @NeilGaetanoLindberg `Blob` does not have a `name` attribute, `File` does.